# Appropriate Aggregate function, or how to get around it

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to do a select statement using a **"CASE"** operation, but it says that my condition (abc.reason) is invalid because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. I've tried adding it to the GROUP BY clause but there is an unnecessary row created in my results table. Any tips?

`SELECT`

```
DISTINCT ID 
,(CASE WHEN reason = 4 THEN null ELSE SUM(quantity*price) END) AS Value
,COUNT(*) AS CountAll
```

FROM TransactionsDB

`GROUP BY ID`

`ORDER BY ID DESC`

If I change my GROUP BY Clause to **`GROUP BY ID, reason`** then my results are:

ID    ---- VALUE ----- COUNTALL

id1 - - 1000    - - - - - 22

id1 - - - NULL  - - - - 1

id2 - - - - 232 - - -- 17

id3 - - - - 113 -- - - 2

id3 - - - - NULL - - 1

When really I need the results:

ID    ---- VALUE ----- COUNTALL

id1 - - 1000    - - - - - **23**

id2 - - - - 232 - - -- 17

id3 - - - - 113 -- - - **3**

Thank you in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ID 
,SUM(CASE WHEN reason = 4 THEN 0 ELSE quantity*price END) AS Value
,COUNT(*) AS CountAll
FROM TransactionsDB
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Comment: Hi Richard, I had this solution before, but Instead I used a SUM(quantity * price) inside of the sum(case when....) and this threw an error. But this works, thank you so much :)!

Comment: I removed the DISTINCT because GROUP BY already does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN reason = 4 THEN 0 ELSE quantity*price END) AS Value,
    COUNT(*) AS CountAll
FROM TransactionsDB
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is exactly the same as the above answer? regardless thank you :)!